# I can use getString of some object inside Done only?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

here the code:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> cities = ParseQuery.getQuery("cities");
        System.out.println("searchable value is " + firstCity);
        cities.whereEqualTo("cityName", firstCity);
        cities.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
           @SuppressWarnings("null")
            public  void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (object == null) {
              System.out.println(object.getString("cityName"));

            } else {
                System.out.println(object.getString("cityName"));

            }
          }
         });
```

Why i cant use object.getString("cityName") outside the Done method?

Comment: You can't return the result of an asynchronous operation, you have to use the callback to call a method that uses the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why i cant use object.getString("cityName") outside the Done method?

Because `object` is an argument in the `done()` method and method arguments are scoped inside the method.

You can call another method passing the `object` reference, or you can e.g. store it to a variable that has broader scope (for example, a class member).

Answer (score 0):

Do your asynchronous operation in [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)